# Problem getting the balance of Phantom wallet with json-rpc request using javascript async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, json-rpc, solana, phantom-wallet

I have a connection to the Phantom wallet.

I'm expecting `phantom_balance()` to return a balance or data containing the balance.

Do I have an error in the `json-rpc` formatting?

I'm getting the following `JsonRpcEngine` failure on the `catch()`.

```
Phantom - RPC Error: JsonRpcEngine: Response has no error or result for request:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1161935556,
  "method": "getBalance",
  "params": [
    "iQKBP3tSX6g3j6pS6g3LuzhoqTQKBP3tSX6g33tSX6g3j6pS6g"
  ]
}
```

Here is the js

```
// get wallet provider, phantom
const get_provider = () => {
  if ("solana" in window) {
    const provider = window.solana;
    if (provider.isPhantom) {
      return provider;
    }
  }
  window.open("https://phantom.app/", "_blank");
};

// async get wallet balance
async function phantom_balance() {
  // alt window.solana
  const phantom = get_provider();
  console.log("Still Connected: " + phantom.isConnected);
  if (phantom.isConnected !== false) {
    const wallet_address = phantom.publicKey.toString();
    console.log("Getting Balance For: " + wallet_address);
 
    // json-rpc request (ERROR!)
      const balance = await phantom.request({
        method: "getBalance",
        params: [wallet_address]
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }).catch(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        });
    
  }
}
```

I have also tried the following and get an error saying `phantom.getBalance()` is not a function.

```
    const balance = await phantom.getBalance(wallet_address)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

I am not currently including any `<script>` in the head of the document. According to Phantom docs, they inject `window.solana` into the document (which also exposes the RPC interface). Maybe I still need web3 in the head in order to access `window.solana.getBalance(wallet_address)` and/or the RPC method `window.solana.request(method: "getBalance")` ??

Comment: Are you trying to read SOL tokens for a given public key? If so you can read it with the `connection.getBalance()`. Docs [here](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getBalance)

Comment: I've updated the question to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working example.

1. Make sure you have the Phantom wallet extension installed. [phantom.app](https://phantom.app/)
2. Include solana-web3 in the head of the document.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
```

3. Make sure your js script has `type="module"` defined.

```
<script type="module" src="/path/to/your/main.js"></script>
```

4. This runs in your main js file.

```
// get wallet provider, phantom
const get_provider = () => {
  if ("solana" in window) {
    const provider = window.solana;
    if (provider.isPhantom) {
      return provider;
    }
  }
  window.open("https://phantom.app/", "_blank");
};

// get balance from connected Phantom wallet
async function phantom_balance() {
  // alt window.solana
  const phantom = get_provider();
  console.log("Wallet Connected: " + phantom.isConnected);
  if (phantom.isConnected !== false) {

    const wallet = phantom.publicKey;
    const wallet_b58 = phantom.publicKey.toString();

    // connect to the cluster
    console.log("Connecting Cluster");
    var connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
      solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
      'confirmed',
    );

    // remember, do not use base 58 encoded key with getBalance();
    console.log("Getting Balance: " + wallet_b58);
    let _balance = await connection.getBalance(wallet)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log("Wallet Balance: " + data);
        return data;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });

  }
}
```

5. Usage

```
var balance = phantom_balance();
```

Returns Lamports Integer

```
992953240
```

Answer (score -2):

This code if you want to get a number not in Lamports
`let _balance = await connection.getBalance(wallet).then(function(data) { console.log("Wallet Balance: " + data / lamports_per_sol); return data; })`